# Installing pgext on Raspbian

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install pgext to use in conjunction with pygame, however when running
    python setup.py install
I get the following error

```
Include path not found (SDL)
SDL: /usr/lib/arm_linux-gnueabihf
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 198, in <module>
  cfgsetup.configure()
File "setup.py", line 167, in configure
  incdirs.append(self.ext_include_dirs[incd])
KeyError: 'SDL'
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: You could ask this on the raspberry pi stack exchange: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to install SDL headers / development package (libsdl1.2-dev).

But pgext was tested only on linux x86, 64 and Win32.
If you get any errors feel free to contact me.